# Split tunnel configuration with OpenVPN not working on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu, openvpn, pfsense

I have Ubuntu 18.04 on my laptop and it has a VPN settings configured on it.

PfSense is the firewall and the VPN server is OpenVPN. Split tunnel is configured on that OpenVPN client. I can confirm others are using the same VPN client configuration on their systems and when they connect to that VPN, they are able to connect to office network and use their local Internet access.

One difference is that most of my colleagues are using Windows or MAC.

On my Ubuntu laptop, the configuration is not allowing the use of my Internet connections when I connect to the VPN. It only allows me to connect to the remote office network, and my local Internet access is unavailable. I have also tried to ping google dns, and the request times out.

Below are the parameters which are the OpenVPN configuration file on my laptop which should allow the split tunnel to work, but it's not working I am not able to identify why.

```
pull-filter ignore "redirect gateway"

route-nopull

route "my workstation ip" 255.255.255.255
```

If you are able to guide me with the details given, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: This very little information to work with. Make a network capture using tcpdump for example to visualize the traffic flow. Analyze the logs. Check your routing table to verify that routing is correctly configured

Comment: maybe use this ansible role to properly configure your openvpn client on Ubuntu. https://github.com/robertdebock/ansible-role-openvpn. Because what you provided is missing a lot of options